# IDE for generating Flowchart LaTeX code

Tags: diagrams, editors

Is there any IDE that allows you to draw flowcharts and generate the LaTeX codes?
I've searched on google but came accross [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/) which is only a library? Is there any IDE support?

Comment: I don't know any dedicated IDE for flowcharts, but `Inkscape` can generate `TikZ` code.

Comment: Not an IDE specifically for flowcharts but `tikzedt` can come handy for them too.

Comment: You can also try ipe, http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many links to various tools working with tikz at [texample resources](http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/) web-page sections (Tools for working with TikZ code, Tools that generate PGF/TikZ code). You can write everything in pure Tikz with editor or use some external program, to convert vector drawing into Tikz code. It's your choise.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [online Flowchart generator](https://latex-editor.pages.dev/graph/) you need to drag and drop nodes to create your flowchart then it will generate the latex code for your graph

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw, rectangle, align=center, minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2.5cm},
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=8cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
]

\node {MRI Scanner Project}
  child {node {Project Initiation}
    child {node {Define Project Scope}}
    child {node {Conduct Feasibility Study}}
    child {node {Obtain Funding}}
  }
  child {node {Procurement}
    child {node {Identify Suppliers}}
    child {node {Evaluate Proposals}}
    child {node {Select Supplier}}
    child {node {Procure MRI Scanner}}
  }
  child {node {Installation}
    child {node {Site Preparation}}
    child {node {Install Scanner}}
    child {node {Testing and QA}}
  }
  child {node {Training}
    child {node {Train Staff}}
    child {node {Coordinate with Supplier}}
  }
  child {node {Documentation}
    child {node {Create Project Docs}}
    child {node {Maintain Records}}
  }
  child {node {Project Closure}
    child {node {Final Inspection}}
    child {node {Handover to Center}}
    child {node {Evaluate Performance}}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```